# What is the definition of 'Idiomatic' as in Idiomatic Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In Anders first talk on TypeScript, he uses the phrase 'idiomatic javascript" several times.

What is the definition of idiomatic as it is used here?

I have looked this up on Wikipedia, SO search etc, but still feel I don't fully understand what the word means in this context.

Greg

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Idiomatic here means "How people who write JavaScript write JavaScript".

It means "Natural to the native speaker".

For example, returning an object is considered by some idiomatic JavaScript:

```
function foo(){
    return {x:3,y:5};
}
var point = foo();
```

While "out parameters" are considered less idiomatic:

```
function foo(out){
    out.point = {x:3,y:5}
}
var out = {};
foo(out);
point = out.point;
```

Another example of idiomatic JavaScript is the use of closures.